# Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects using Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape information from this website https://www.gumtree.co.za, however I am not sure how to get the URL of the property.

This is what I have:

```
class GumtreeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "gumtree"
    start_urls = ['https://www.gumtree.co.za/s-house-rentals-flat-rentals-offered/cape-town/v1c9071l3100006p1',
                  'https://www.gumtree.co.za/s-houses-flats-for-sale/cape-town/v1c9074l3100006p1']

    def parse(self, response):

        for prop in response.css('div.tileV1'):
            link = 'https://www.gumtree.co.za' + prop.css('div.title  a.tile-title-text::attr(href)').get()
```

I have tried multiple combinations however I cannot seem to get it right. Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to scrape exactly in the page? The ad list in the carousel in the top?

If yes, you need to look at the Javascript XHR requests, they are loaded dynamically so you have to inspect the different requests to find what you want.

Comment: I am trying to get the link of the actual property, to retrieve other information about it, so for example a specific house, and I want to be able to retrieve the link of the property ( https://www.gumtree.co.za/s-house-rentals-flat-rentals-offered/cape-town/page-3/v1c9071l3100006p3) this, as an example. @Guillaume